# @apollo/client error-React Hook "useQuery" is called in function which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I get the following error when i make graphql api call using @apollo/client

React Hook "useQuery" is called in function "graphqlService" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

**Index file:**

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:3008",
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

 ReactDOM.render(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
       <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>,       
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

**Functional component file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {  
  useQuery,
  gql
} from "@apollo/client";
import Schema from '../models/schema';

function graphqlService( params : any = {} ) {
  const query = Schema.getPanelData;
  const { data } = useQuery(query, {variables: params});

  if (data) return data;     
}
```

export default graphqlService;

**Class Component file:**

```
this.data = graphqlService(params);
```

I do not think it is issue in package, i am using same package in same in POC project. There it is working fine. Only difference is i had written all code in same file, here i have written in 2 different files.

Comment: As the errors states, you can't use hooks outside of components. Your ```graphqlService``` is not a component

Comment: i have created a functional component where i am using UseQuery method and calling that functional component from Class component . Still i get the same error.i updated above method to functional component eg: function graphqlService( params : any = {} ) {}

Comment: Without seeing the functional component, we can't help you.

Comment: i updated the above query, please check

Comment: Your graphqlService is not a component. Please read the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Could you please help me to understand how my component is different from above link. Only difference i see is i am not using render method. I want to just return data, not to return html. I cannot do this? Please guide me with example.

Comment: "This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element" - components must return React element. Your function returns data instead, so it won't work. Seems like you then try to assign that data to some variable. That won't work. You will need to do more reading around how React works and changed the design of your app

Comment: you don't need a separate service file ... just rename graphqlService to some 'GraphqlPoweredComponent' and use as component, just return renderable (you can return pure data only in custom hook, to be rendered in other component) content "loading", "error" and 'data' (use .map if it is an array)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue in a functional component which is for sure correct. I fixed this error message by using a Capital letter for the component name.

Why it needs a capital letter is described in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import Query from "./Query";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const ComponentName = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Query);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  return (
    ...
  );
};
export default ComponentName;
```

Answer (score -1):

The useQuery hook can only be call in react component (cf : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/)

Comment: i have created a functional component where i am using UseQuery method and calling that functional component from Class component . Still i get the same error.i updated above method to functional component function graphqlService( params : any = {} ) {}